# Undo a redaction in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

Is it possible to undo a redaction that has been applied in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro (put aside re-launching the PDF, provided that the PDF was saved before the redaction was applied)?

I use Adobe Acrobat XI Pro with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to undo a redaction that has been applied in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro.